# Grails UrlMappings to rewrite static URLs

Tags: grails

I'm trying to do something like this in `UrlMappings` to re-write and shorten URLs for static HTML:

```
mappings = {
   "/page/$pageId" {
      uri = {
       "/foo/bar/pages/${pageId}.html"
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

The goal is to dispatch a URL like `/page/xyz` to `/foo/bar/pages/xyz.html`.

I haven't been able to get the above syntax to work - Grails does not seem to like a closure as the value for a URI.

I also tried without a closure

```
"/page/$pageId"(uri: "/foo/bar/pages/${pageId}.html")
```

and got a 404: /foo/bar/pages/(*).html not found.

I am on Grails 2.2.2.

Comment: Well if you relabeled xyz.html to xyz.gsp  in the views directory then you could do a seperate mapping "/page/xyz"(view:'xyz')

Answer (score 0):

When mapping to a specific URI you don't use a closure. As demonstrated in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#urlmappings):

> To rewrite one URI onto another explicit URI (rather than a
>   controller/action pair) do something like this:

```
"/hello"(uri: "/hello.dispatch")
```

So in your case:

```
"/page/$pageId"(uri: "/foo/bar/pages/${pageId}.html")
```

Comment: That resulted in 404 - see abobve